# EdmFunction must be qualified with model name?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Book "Johnson Glenn -  Accessing Data with Microsoft .NET Framework 4 - 2011" contains example of custom function, and call of function:

```
gv.DataSource = (... select new { ... , ModelDefinedFunctions.Detail(..)});
```

But on CD in practice tests with that book:

```
var instructors = from p in context.People
                  where YearsSince((DateTime)p.HireDate) > 10
                  select p;
```

and explanation: You must refer to the custom function using the method name. The method name must not be qualified with the model name. The method requires a DateTime parameter and this must be included.

Don't have VS now, what is the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModelDefinedFunctions` is the name of the class where the method `Detail` is defined. The two approaches are identical. There is no qualifier for the model name.